# default constructor call vs. copy constructor call

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

if I create three objects like this:

```
A myA; // line 1
A myA2 = A(); // line 2
A myA3 = myA; // line 3
```

I thought in the second line the copy constructor is called. But if I try this (Visual Studio) line 1 and line 2 calls only the default constructor. Whereas of course line 3 calls the copy constructor. So it seems there is no difference between line 1 and line 2. Both calls the default construcor. So why I have the different syntax?

By the way my testclass A has the form:

```
class A { 
  public:
   A() { cout << "default ctor is called..." << endl; }
   A(const A &obj) { cout << "copy ctor is called..." << endl; }
};
```

Comment: See: [What are copy elision and return-value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

Comment: Look up "copy elision"

Answer (score 0):

The copy constructor calling is optimized according to [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision); which is guaranteed since C++17.

> In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object